# Changing .prop using jQuery does not trigger .change event

Tags: jquery

I've got an event listener on a checkbox:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="something">
```

My event listener:

```
$('input[type="checkbox"][name="something"]').change(function() { 
    //DO SOMETHING 
});
```

I have another event listener that changes `.prop` of the checkbox:

```
$('#button').click(function() { 
    $('input[type="checkbox"][name="something"]').prop("checked", false);
});
```

When I check the checkbox `DO SOMETHING` triggers. When I click on the `#button`, the `.prop` changes and I see the checkbox visually uncheck, but `DO SOMETHING` doesn't get triggered...

Something I'm overlooking?

Comment: possible duplicate of [checkbox checked with prop() does not fire events attached to "change"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19505011/checkbox-checked-with-prop-does-not-fire-events-attached-to-change)

Answer (score 253, accepted):

Change event is fired when the value is changed by users interaction on page and not when value is modified using code.

Here you need to use `.trigger('change')` after changing the property:

```
$('input[type="checkbox"][name="something"]').prop('checked', false).trigger('change');
```

**[Working Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/K33H8/)**

Comment: I thought `prop` took care of change event generation?

Comment: Thanks! So the reason why .prop().change() didn't work on my end is because I'm doing jQuery in MeteorJS, which has a slightly different way of calling jQuery. I tried it your way exactly and it worked.

Comment: @fuzzybabybunny: it is not because of MeteorJS. prop() does not trigger change event.

Comment: @MilindAnantwar, I was doing .prop followed by .change in Meteor code (`Template.myTemplate.events`) and it didn't work. I then put the same exact jQuery code under `Template.myTemplate.rendered` and it ran fine.

Comment: @MilindAnantwar here is a scenario if on change there is an event, but i don't want to trigger that function

Comment: @MudassarZahid: just add the if condition(on which you do not want to trigger the change event) as check in change function.

Comment: for those to whom this answer is not working, the problem is not in the answer but in the way the change is captured. use `$(document).on('change'...` instead of `.change(function(e)...`

Comment: Or use .click() if the watched event is on("click, function()

Answer (score 2):

**Updated version**

`.change()` is already deprecated

Use `.trigger('change')` instead

```
$('input[type="checkbox"][name="something"]').prop("checked", false).trigger('change');
```

Source: https://api.jquery.com/change-shorthand/#change-handler

Comment: I can not find any official information about .change() being deprecated. Where did you get that information?

Comment: @UlfR From [here](https://api.jquery.com/change-shorthand/#change-handler).