# Check radio button on div click + prettyPhoto

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a small problem and I don't know how I can get this working...

I display 3 images with a radio button under the images. If someone clicks on a small image above the radio button, a lightbox opens the full image.

If someone clicks on the image, I want to open the lightbox and check the radio button under the small image.

I'm using this javascript code (+ prettyphoto script).

```
<script type="text/javascript">jQuery(function($){
$('.parentdiv').click(function() {
  $(this).find('input').prop('checked', true)    
});
});</script>
```

and this html code:

```
<div class="parentdiv">
    <a data-rel="prettyPhoto[5150]" rel="prettyPhoto[5150]" title=" Option 1" href="xxx1.jpg">

        <img alt=" Option 1" title=" Option 1" src="xxx1.jpg" />
    </a>
    <input id="image-1" type="radio" checked="checked" value="2394" name="image[5150]" />
</div>
<div class="parentdiv">
    <a data-rel="prettyPhoto[5150]" rel="prettyPhoto[5150]" title=" Option 2" href="xxx2.jpg">
        <img alt="Option 2" title="Option 2" src="xxx2.jpg" />
    </a>
    <input id="image-2" type="radio" value="2400" name="image[5150]" />
</div>
<div class="parentdiv">
    <a data-rel="prettyPhoto[5150]" rel="prettyPhoto[5150]" title=" Option 3" href="xxx3.jpg">
        <img alt="Option 3" title="Option 3" src="xxx3.jpg" />
    </a>
    <input id="image-3" type="radio" value="2405" name="image[5150]" />
</div>
```

But it's not working. Only the lightbox triggers. If I click under the image, next to the radio button, the radio button is checked. So it is somehow working, but not if I click on the image-link ...

Hope someone can help me.

best

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Of course not, as the prettyphoto prevents the default handler from running, otherwise the browser'd open the image by itself.

You might try to attach another event handler to the links themselves.

Like

```
$('a[rel]').click(function() {
  $(this).parent().find('input').prop('checked', true)    
});
```

Comment: and afterwards, trigger change if you need to `$(this).parent().find('input').prop('checked', true).change()`, source:    https://stackoverflow.com/a/24410621/1063287