# Select all checkbox only works visually

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

i created a table and a checkbox for each column of this table in a sidebar to show or hide that column and also a select all checkbox.

problem is all checkboxes work fine , but select all checkbox works only visually ,it checks all the checkboxes but it doesn't show or hide all the columns as it should.

this is checkbox code :

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("input:checkbox:not(:checked)").each(function() {
        var column = "table ." + $(this).attr("name");
        $(column).hide();
    });

    $("input:checkbox").click(function() {
        var column = "table ." + $(this).attr("name");
        $(column).toggle();
    });
});
```

and select all checkbox code :

```
$('#select-all').on('change', function (e) {
    var $inputs = $('#checkboxlist input[type=checkbox]');
    if (e.originalEvent === undefined) {
        var allChecked = true;
        $inputs.each(function () {
            allChecked = allChecked && this.checked;
        });
        this.checked = allChecked;
    } else {
        $inputs.prop('checked', this.checked);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**1st:** Up to [Difference between change and click event of checkbox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24410581/changing-prop-using-jquery-does-not-trigger-change-event) you need to replace your click event by a change event

```
$("input:checkbox").change(function() {
    var column = "table ." + $(this).attr("name");
    $(column).toggle();
});
```

**2nd:** Up to [trigger the change event](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24410581/changing-prop-using-jquery-does-not-trigger-change-event) you'll need to use `.change()` or `.trigger('change')`.

```
$inputs.prop('checked', this.checked).change();
```

Comment: @MiLaDA add change event and then use `$inputs.prop('checked', this.checked).trigger('change')` or `$inputs.prop('checked', this.checked).change()`

Comment: Thank You Basti and Mohamed, changing the click event and trigering the change event in the end was the solution :)

Comment: @Mohamed-Yousef why did you remove the hide/show part? I think this is important for his use case!

Comment: Sorry Basti I edited your answer to keep everything clear for @MiLaDA and anyone will come on the future .. Have a great day Basti & MiLaDA

Comment: Basti its not an important part it's just a more of code .. he/she didn't need to make another action while he/she already use `.toggle()` on his code .. be clear , be specific in the problem which the OP come with .. It'll be good to gain good reputation .. Good Luck :)

Answer (score 0):

```
$("input:checkbox").on('change',function() {
```

This should work fine...