# hide a form attribute without "hiding" the boostrap row col-4 using jquery

Tags: jquery, html, css, bootstrap-4

I need to be able to hide the form1 but NOT the col-4-md bootstrap space that it takes up. When I hide form1, form2 which is in the same row gets pushed over the 4-col spacing. The short one minute video might the be the easiest way to see what I am trying to do.

**HTML Code:**

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-1"> </div>
<input type="submit" class="col-4 btn btn-success" id="delivery_btn" value="Enter Delivery Address"></input> 
<div class="col-2 center"> OR </div>
  <input type="submit" class="col-4 btn btn-success" id="pickup_btn" value="Find Pickup Location"></input>
<div class="col-1"> </div>
</div>

<div class="row">
    <div class="col-1"> </div>
    <form class="col-4" id='form1'>

      <label>Enter Address</label>
    <input type="text" placeholder="Example: 123 Main St."></input> <br>
  <label>Enter Zip Code</label>
    <input type="text" placeholder="Enter Zip Code"></input> <br>
    <input type="submit"></input>
</form> 
<div class="col-2"></div>

   <form class="col-4" id='form2'>
<input type="text" value="Zip"></input ><br>
    <input type="submit" value="search"></input>
</form> 
</div>
```

**Jquery Code**

```
$('#delivery_btn').on('click', function(){
  $('#form1').toggle();

});

$('#pickup_btn').on('click', function(){
  $('#form2').toggle();
});
```

Using prop like [Changing .prop using jQuery does not trigger .change event](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24410581/changing-prop-using-jquery-does-not-trigger-change-event) was one idea I had, but prop is NOT supported on IE. Plus I am not even sure if it would work as it would probably still hide the col-4 as well.

I am sure there could be a easy way to solve what I am trying to do. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Use the CSS style [Visibility](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/visibility).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One approach is using `toggle()` over the form's childrens, basically like this:

```
$('#delivery_btn').on('click', function()
{
    $('#form1').children().toggle();
});

$('#pickup_btn').on('click', function()
{
    $('#form2').children().toggle();
});
```

However, I will use an edited version of the skeleton you have to get a better Bootstrap template, check the example:

```js
$(document).ready(function()
{
    $("#form2").hide();
});

$('#delivery_btn, #pickup_btn').on('click', function()
{
    $('#form1, #form2').slideToggle();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.6/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-wHAiFfRlMFy6i5SRaxvfOCifBUQy1xHdJ/yoi7FRNXMRBu5WHdZYu1hA6ZOblgut" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.2.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-GJzZqFGwb1QTTN6wy59ffF1BuGJpLSa9DkKMp0DgiMDm4iYMj70gZWKYbI706tWS" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.2.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-B0UglyR+jN6CkvvICOB2joaf5I4l3gm9GU6Hc1og6Ls7i6U/mkkaduKaBhlAXv9k" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<div class="container-fluid">

<div class="row">

  <div class="offset-1 col-4">
    <button class="btn btn-success btn-block" id="delivery_btn">
      Enter Delivery Address
    </button>
  </div>
  
  <div class="col-2 text-center">OR</div>

  <div class="col-4">
    <button class="btn btn-success btn-block" id="pickup_btn">
      Find Pickup Location
    </button>
  </div>

</div>

<div class="row">

  <div class="offset-1 col-4 mt-1">
    <form id='form1'>
      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="address">Enter Address</label>
        <input class="form-control" type="text" placeholder="Example: 123 Main St." id="address">  
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="zip">Enter Zip Code</label>
        <input class="form-control" type="text" placeholder="Enter Zip Code" id="zip">
      </div>
      <button type="submit" class="btn btn-info btn-block">
        Submit
      </button>
    </form>
  </div>

  <div class="offset-2 col-4 mt-1">
    <form id='form2'>
      <div class="form-group">
        <input class="form-control" type="text" value="Zip">
      </div>
      <button class="btn btn-warning btn-block" type="submit">
        Search
      </button>
    </form>
  </div>

</div>

</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

There is a little mistake in html and jquery code

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.2.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-GJzZqFGwb1QTTN6wy59ffF1BuGJpLSa9DkKMp0DgiMDm4iYMj70gZWKYbI706tWS" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="row">
 <div class="col-1"> </div>
 <input type="submit" class="col-4 btn btn-success" id="delivery_btn" value="Enter Delivery Address">
</input> 
<div class="col-2 center"> OR </div>
<input type="submit" class="col-4 btn btn-success" id="pickup_btn" value="Find Pickup Location"></input>
<div class="col-1"> </div>
</div>

<div class="row">
 <div class="col-1"> </div>
 <div class="col-4">
  
  <form id='form1'>
   <label>Enter Address</label>
   <input type="text" placeholder="Example: 123 Main St."></input> <br>
   <label>Enter Zip Code</label>
   <input type="text" placeholder="Enter Zip Code"></input> <br>
   <input type="submit"></input>
  </form> 
 </div>
 <div class="col-2"></div>
 <div class="col-4">
  <form id='form2'>
   <input type="text" value="Zip"></input ><br>
   <input type="submit" value="search"></input>
  </form> 
 </div>
</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
 $('#delivery_btn').on('click', function(){
  $('#form1').toggle();
  $('#form2').hide();
 });
  
 $('#pickup_btn').on('click', function(){
  $('#form2').toggle();
  $('#form1').hide();
 });

</script>
```

Comment: interesting you did it without the visibility like everyone else. and yours toggles back and forth too like the actual papa johns website. what was my error? thanks for answer!

Comment: making this `<div class="col-4">` one line above
  
  `<form id='form1'>` makes alot of sense as they are technically separate now (but one at the same time). i am guesssing thats how you solved this without using visible.

Comment: you first need to understand, how Grid in bootstrap actually works, check the link below.
https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.2/layout/grid/

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve that by setting the form's `visibility` style to `hidden` or `opacity` to `0`.

```
$('#delivery_btn').toggle(function(){
    $('#form1').css({'visibility': 'hidden'});
}, function() {
    $('#form1').css({'visibility': 'visible'});
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.6/umd/popper.min.js" ></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.2.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" >
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.2.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" ></script>

<div class="container-fluid">

<div class="row">

  <div class="col-md-5 col-xs-10">
    <button class="btn btn-success btn-block" id="delivery_btn">
      Enter Delivery Address
    </button>
  </div>

  <div class="col-md-2 col-xs-10 text-center"><h2>==OR==</h2></div>

  <div class="col-md-5 col-xs-10">
    <button class="btn btn-success btn-block" id="pickup_btn">
      Find Pickup Location
    </button>
  </div>

</div>

<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-5 col-xs-10 mt-1">
    <form id='form1'>
      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="address">Enter Address</label>
        <input class="form-control" type="text" placeholder="Example: 123 Main St." id="address">  
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="zip">Enter Zip Code</label>
        <input class="form-control" type="text" placeholder="Enter Zip Code" id="zip">
      </div>
      <button type="submit" class="btn btn-info btn-block">
        Submit
      </button>
    </form>
  </div>

  <div class="col-md-2 col-xs-10 text-center"></div>

  <div class="col-md-5 col-xs-10 mt-1">
    <form id='form2'>
      <div class="form-group">
        <input class="form-control" type="text" value="Zip">
      </div>
      <button class="btn btn-warning btn-block" type="submit">
        Search
      </button>
    </form>
  </div>

</div>

</div>

<br><br><br>

<div class="control-group">
    <h1>Radio buttons</h1>
    <label class="control control--radio">First radio
      <input type="radio" name="radio" checked="checked"/>
      <div class="control__indicator"></div>
    </label>
    <label class="control control--radio">Second radio
      <input type="radio" name="radio"/>
      <div class="control__indicator"></div>
    </label>

  </div>
```

Javascript:

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
    $("#form2").hide();
});

$('#delivery_btn, #pickup_btn').on('click', function()
{
    $('#form1, #form2').slideToggle();
});
```

CSS:

```
.control-group{
  display inline-block
  vertical-align top
  background $color--white
  text-align left
  box-shadow 0 1px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1)
  padding 30px
  width 200px
  height 210px
  margin 10px
}

.control {
  display block
  position relative
  padding-left 30px
  margin-bottom 15px
  cursor pointer
  font-size 18px
}
```