# JQuery Listener Firing Twice

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm sure this is simple, but everything I read claims that changing a `prop` or `attr` value won't execute a change listener. In my case it does.

```js
$(document).on('keyup change', '.fire', function(e){
  console.log("submit");
  $(".editQuoteForm :input:not([type=hidden])").prop("disabled", true);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form class="editQuoteForm">
  <input type="text" class="fire">
</form>
```

This listener outputs "submit" to the console twice. When I remove the line of code that disables all the input fields, it works as expected. How can I prevent the code that disables the fields from firing the event a second time?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You example is unclear. You have `class='fire'` in your html and `keyup change` events for `class='submit-later'`?

Comment: @dganenco I'm sorry, both classes should be `fire`. I've fixed the question

Comment: @TylerRoper or click outside after input also will trigger change event

Comment: @ScottMarcus Disabling the element in the `keyup` causes it to lose focus, which in turn fires a `change` event, no?

Comment: @TylerRoper Ok, so how can I disable it and prevent the change event? I need the change event for cases where autofill is used to complete the form.

Comment: Just check the `target` of the event and the event name to determine what to do in the handler.

Comment: @ScottMarcus This is why I understood prop to not fire the change event. https://stackoverflow.com/a/24410621/7426461 I'm completely happy being wrong, just trying to get this fixed.

Comment: Also, unrelated, but `keyup` only fires when you release a key obviously. This means I could hold down a key for 3 seconds and have a 10 character string in the input. Not clear what your intention is but it seemed worthwhile to point out.

Comment: I'm implementing an address form that a user can either type in their information or user autofill to complete the form. Once they do, the form should submit. In my actual application, I have this listener calling a debounce function and the disable field code is in a .submit() listener since I actually have multiple listener types. But the goal is to simply disable the fields while it's submitting and the response enables the fields again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not just check the event source? If it is `disabled`, then do nothing.

```js
$(document).on('keyup change', '.fire', function(e){
  // Only run the rest of the code if the source of the event
  // wasn't a field that is now disabled.
  if(!e.target.disabled){
    console.log("submit");
    $(".editQuoteForm :input:not([type=hidden])").prop("disabled", true);
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form class="editQuoteForm">
  <input type="text" class="fire">
  <input type="text" class="fire">
  <input type="text" class="fire">
  <input type="text" class="fire">
  <input type="text" class="fire">
  <input type="text" class="fire">
</form>
```

Answer (score 1):

One solution would be checking for the disabled state of the target input before issuing the next statements.

On focus loss triggered by setting the property `disabled`, the `change` event is fired.

```js
$(document).on('keyup change', '.fire', function(e){
  if (e.target.disabled) return false;
  console.log("submit");
  $(".editQuoteForm :input:not([type=hidden])").prop("disabled", true);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form class="editQuoteForm">
  <input type="text" class="fire">
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code trigger twice because you listen to keyup and change. 
Keyup event trigger first then following with change.

> Why would do you need change? if keyup already do what do you want. :)

If you need the two event at once. You can do this way to prevent multiple trigger.

```
$(document).on('keyup change', '.fire', function (e) {
    if ($(".editQuoteForm :input:not([type=hidden])").prop("disabled") == false) {
        console.log("submit");
        $(".editQuoteForm :input:not([type=hidden])").prop("disabled", true);
        // after process finish
        $(".editQuoteForm :input:not([type=hidden])").prop("disabled", false);
    }
});
```

Comment: I need `change` because it picks up autofill. This is for an address form. Keyup doesn't pick up autofill in firefox or edge. However, it will in chrome.

Comment: That's incorrect, attaching multiple listeners doesn't mean they fire multiple times.

Comment: You can check disabled status first before executing any code.

Comment: Please try the code snippet in the question and observe the event firing just once.

Comment: @AnuragSrivastava Just typing something in wouldn't trigger `change`, sure, but if you fire the `change` by pressing something like **Enter**, it does fire twice. I think the real confusion here is what OP means by "fires twice".

Comment: @TylerRoper Well it should right? Agreed that OP is confused about the events.

Comment: OP's now-working snippet provides clarity. The disable is throwing the `change` event.

Comment: @TylerRoper Because on focus loss the `change` event is called.

Comment: Any change call like change disabled to true from javascript will not trigger the change event

Answer (score 0):

I had reproduced your problem right now, and it is caused by your event handlers. `change` and `keyup` are firing both on each input. You have to think about it and to choose the appropriate event, OR you can separate your logic based on `e.type`, but I would not recommend to do it.

Comment: Please try the code snippet in the question and observe the event firing just once.

Comment: @AnuragSrivastava I just now wrote that I REPRODUCED it using provided snippet

Comment: `your event handlers. change and keyup are firing both on each input` -> Incorrect

Comment: @AnuragSrivastava please consider to add any evidence of yours point of view if you are not agree