# jquery - calculate all checkbox checked with checkAll button

Tags: jquery

I have script that sum all checked checkboxs values inside div with class="show_list_item". and it's working fine.

I also have script that allow user to check all checkboxs with one click (id="checkAll"). it's also working well.

When user use the "checkall" button the script doesn't calculate the selected/checked values anymore.

How can i fix it?

JQUERY

```
// CALCULATE TOTAL CHECKED
$('input:checkbox').change(function ()
{
    var total_srvs_amount = 0;
    $('.show_list_item input[name="amount"]:checkbox:checked').each(function(){ 
        
        total_srvs_amount += isNaN($(this).val()) ? 0 : Number ($(this).val());
        
    }); 
    
    $("#total_sum").text(total_srvs_amount);
});

// CHECK ALL CHECKBOXS
$(function () {
    var chkMain = $('.checkAll input:checkbox#checkAll , .checkAll input:checkbox.checkAllBtn');
    $(chkMain).change(function () {
        $('.checkAll input:checkbox').not(this).prop('checked', this.checked);

    });

});
```

HTML

```
<div id="1" class="obj_res_box show_list_item">

    <input type="checkbox" class="" value="" id="checkAll">

    <table class="checkAll">
        <tr>
            <td><input type="checkbox" name="amount" value="138.75"></td>
            <td><input type="checkbox" name="amount" value="120"></td>
            <td><input type="checkbox" name="amount" value="64"></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>

<div id="2" class="obj_res_box hide_list_item">
....
</div>

<div id="total_sum">0</div>
```

Comment: You can manually trigger the change event on the class: `$('.checkAll input:checkbox').not(this).prop('checked', this.checked).trigger('change')`.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Changing .prop using jQuery does not trigger .change event](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24410581/changing-prop-using-jquery-does-not-trigger-change-event)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There was mistake in // CHECK ALL CHECKBOXS function.

I have corrected it. Please review

```js
// CALCULATE TOTAL CHECKED
$('input:checkbox').change(function ()
{
    var total_srvs_amount = 0;
    $('.show_list_item input[name="amount"]:checkbox:checked').each(function(){ 
        
        total_srvs_amount += isNaN($(this).val()) ? 0 : Number ($(this).val());
        
    }); 
    
    $("#total_sum").text(total_srvs_amount);
});

// CHECK ALL CHECKBOXS
$(function () {
    var chkMain = $('input:checkbox#checkAll');
    $(chkMain).change(function () {
        $('.checkAll input:checkbox').prop('checked', this.checked);
       $('.checkAll input:checkbox').trigger('change');
    });

});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="1" class="obj_res_box show_list_item">

    <input type="checkbox" class="" value="" id="checkAll">

    <table class="checkAll">
        <tr>
            <td><input type="checkbox" name="amount" value="138.75"></td>
            <td><input type="checkbox" name="amount" value="120"></td>
            <td><input type="checkbox" name="amount" value="64"></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>

<div id="2" class="obj_res_box hide_list_item">
....
</div>

<div id="total_sum">0</div>
```

Comment: Thanks. the "checkAll" button working (same as before) but it only calculate checkboxs values when i double click it (when i remove the checkboxs by click on it checkAll button again)