# kendo dropDownList onclick of text change event not firing

Tags: javascript, jquery, checkbox, kendo-ui

I am using kendo UI.
I have a dropdown list of checkboxes.
The onchange event is fireing when user clicks on checkbox. But the event is not firing when user clicks on text.

Thanks in advance for ur help!
-Sai.

```
<script type="text/x-kendo-template" id="CheckboxTemplate">
    <li unselectable="on" class="k-item nowrap check-item">
        <input type="checkbox" name="#= text #" value="#= value #" class="check-input showcolname" checked />
        <span>#= text #</span>
     </li>
</script>


function populateDropdown() {           
        dropdown = $("#dropDownList").kendoDropDownList({
           dataTextField: "text",
           dataValueField: "value",
           template: $("#CheckboxTemplate").html(),
           dataSource: displayColumns,             
           placeholder: "Select...",
            select: function(e) {
                e.preventDefault();
            }
       }).data("kendoDropDownList");

        dropdown.list.width(250);

        dropdown.list.find(".check-input,.check-item").bind("click", function(e) {
            var $item = $(this);
            var $input;         
            if($item.hasClass("check-item")) {
                // Text was clicked
                $input = $item.children(".check-input");
                $input.prop("checked", !$input.is(':checked'));
            } else {
                // Checkbox was clicked
                $input = $item;                                   
            }                                    
            // Check all clicked?
            if($input.val() == "") dropdown.list.find(".check-input").prop("checked", $input.is(':checked'));
            syncColumns();

            e.stopImmediatePropagation();
        });

    }
```

function syncColumns(){

```
 $('.showcolname').each(function() {
              $(this).change(function(event) {
                   event.preventDefault();
                   var val = $(this).val();
                   var url = "${rootContext}${MyUrl}/"+val+"/"+this.checked;
                   var beforeSendCallBack = function() {};
                   var successCallback = function(data) {};
                   submitPost(url, beforeSendCallBack, successCallback, '','');
                  });
          });
```

}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Then you change checked property using Jquery prop method input does not fire change event. So you have to fire it manually using Jquery trigger. For more info look at this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19505011/checkbox-checked-with-prop-does-not-fire-events-attached-to-change). Also yo have to register event bind before trigger it, or use Jquery on.