# Unsaved changes on page refresh, using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to do this :
- When I click the checkbox `"div=true"` or `"div=flase"`, will be shown or hidden
- Status of `checkbox` to be saved and with this, even  the last method called to be saved

Problem
- Status of `checkbox` is saved at refresh of page, but the last method called is not saved.

I do not understand where is my mistake.

Here is the code:

```
<input type='checkbox' id='LineOp' />  Show/Hide Weekends
<div id="true">
    <p>Hide weekend</p>
</div>
<div id="false">
    <p>Show weekend</p>
</div>



function SaveLastCheck() {
    var getStstus = localStorage.getItem("LineOp");

    if (getStstus === "true")
        $("#LineOp").prop("checked", true);

    $("#LineOp").click(function(){
        localStorage.setItem('LineOp', $(this).prop("checked"));
    });

}

$(document).ready(function() {
    SaveLastCheck();
});

$(document).ready(function show_weekends () {
    var checkbox = $('#LineOp'); 
    var dependent = $('#true');
    if (checkbox.attr('checked') !== undefined){
      dependent.show();

    } else {
        dependent.hide();

    }

    checkbox.change(function(e){
       dependent.toggle(); 
    });
});


$(document).ready(function hide_weekends () {
    var checkbox = $('#LineOp'); 
    var dependent = $('#false');
    if (checkbox.attr('checked') == undefined){
      dependent.show();

    } else {
        dependent.hide();

    }

    checkbox.change(function(e){
       dependent.toggle(); 
    });
});
```

HERE IS MY EXAMPLE http://jsfiddle.net/b3g6arbd/4/

Comment: possible duplicate of [checkbox checked with prop() does not fire events attached to "change"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19505011/checkbox-checked-with-prop-does-not-fire-events-attached-to-change)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It will work if you use jQuery's [is()](http://api.jquery.com/is/) for checking the initial state and you can shorten your code by passing the checkbox state to [`toggle`](http://api.jquery.com/toggle/). Then you won't need to duplicate your code.

E.g.:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    SaveLastCheck();

    var checkbox = $('#LineOp'); 
    $('#true').toggle(checkbox.is(':checked'));
    $('#false').toggle(!checkbox.is(':checked'));
    checkbox .change(function () {
        $('#true').toggle(this.checked);
        $('#false').toggle(!this.checked);
    });
});
```

Here is the updated example: http://jsfiddle.net/b3g6arbd/12/

Also see [this question and the answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/901712/check-checkbox-checked-property) for more examples on checking a checkbox' state.

Comment: @Silviu : Please mark the answer as accepted then (checkmark next to the answer) and since you are a new user, please take the tour to learn how to use stackoverflow: http://stackoverflow.com/tour