# why isn't the checkbox change event triggered when i do it programatically in d3js

Tags: d3.js

So I have a function that changes the checkbox

```
somefunction() {
    d3.select("input").property("checked", true);
}
```

and in another function I have that detects a change in the checkbox like this:

```
d3.selectAll("input").on("change", change);
```

The problem I have is when it changes the checkbox without me clicking on it, it will not detect it as a "proper" change. What can I do to make it detect something else changing it as a "proper" change?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`d3` is using the standard [addEventListener](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/blob/master/src/selection/on.js#L53) in it's `on` method.  The problem you have is that changing the *checked* property [doesn't raise any events](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19505011/checkbox-checked-with-prop-does-not-fire-events-attached-to-change) for the `addEventListener` to hear.  The proper way would be to just call the handler yourself after setting the proptery:

```
var myInput = d3.select("input");
myInput.property("checked", true);
myInput.on("change")(); // call it yourself
```

Full working code:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

  <head>
    <script data-require="d3@3.5.3" data-semver="3.5.3" src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.5.3/d3.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body>
    <input type="checkbox" />
    <script>
      
      var checked = false;
      setInterval(function(){
        checked = !checked;
        var myInput = d3.select("input");
        myInput.property("checked", checked);
        myInput.on("change")();
      }, 2000);
      
      
      d3.select("input").on("change", function(d){
        console.log('checkbox changed');
      });

    </script>
  </body>

</html>
```

Comment: for some reason, for my particular code, it didn't like it when I set the property to checked and instead preferred true. But it works, so thanks!k

Comment: @KNN.T, I'm not setting it to the string "checked" but to a boolean variable named checked.  Sorry I snipped it from my larger code sample.

Answer (score 1):

The solution suggested by Mark works flawlessly however just alternatively I would also like to mention that rather than calling the event handler yourself you can trigger the event yourself and leave rest of the code as it is. The onchange event is triggered on following sequence focus-valueChange-unfocus. Now this does not happen when you change it without clicking on it, the value changes but no focus. Anyway so instead of relying on that you can just trigger onchange event yourself. I created a fiddle here which explains it. Hope it helps: https://jsfiddle.net/xcjje9r3/6/

```js
window.clickMe = function() {
  tmp = d3.select('#cbox');
  if (tmp.property('checked') == false) tmp.property('checked', true);
  else tmp.property('checked', false);
  tmp.node().dispatchEvent(evt); //MANUALLY TRIGGER EVENT
}

window.listenerInitialize = function() {
  evt = document.createEvent("HTMLEvents"); //CREATE NEW EVENT WITH TYPE
  evt.initEvent("change", false, true); //THE EXACT EVENT TO FIRE
  d3.select('#cbox').on('change', alerting); //ADDING LISTENER FOR EVENT
}

window.alerting = function() {
  alert('testEvent');
}
```

Comment: This is the right answer, calling change manually only works if you don't use parameters of the event (e.g. `e.target`). The important part of the answer is: `d3.select('#cbox').node().dispatchEvent(new Event('change', {'bubbles': false, 'cancelable': true});`.